# In polynomial curve fitting, why do all values have the same error weight?

Tags: error, curve-fitting, measurement-error

Often measured data has a percentage error.  For example, a 2% error on values between 1 and 50, would mean errors between 0.02 and 1.0.

Why does normal polynomial curve fitting not take this into account? With this kind of data, shouldn't curve-fit-errors have a variable weight, depending on the absolute value of the measurement?

Comment: Whether fitting to the smallest absolute error or lowest percent error can depend on how experimental data is gathered for modeling, and also scaling of the data. As an example, when taking temperature measurements using degrees Celsius, measurements near zero degrees will have very large percentage errors even though the absolute experimental error is the same as measurements take near 100 degrees.

Comment: @JamesPhillips In your temperature example, there's (more of) an absolute error, so the standard curve fitting does the correct thing. But with voltage measurements for example, the error is more like a percentage.

Comment: In such cases - and there are many - I fit to the lowest percent error and not the lowest absolute error. So the target fit statistic depends on what I need to do, although the lowest absolute error is usually good enough this is not always the case as you note. I have several different fitting targets available on my zunzun.com web site for exactly this reason, there are other software packages that also have options such as lowest orthogonal error, etc.